# Metamask encountered an error

Tags: metamask

[image]

This method only supports 0x/prefixed hex

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hi! Could you provide more details about what caused this error? Also, you may want to contact MetaMask's support - they should be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Metamask Community Forum](https://community.metamask.io/c/developer-questions/11).

*Users have recently reported receiving the error "Error: This method only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings but input was: "*

*Our developers are aware and working on investigating further.*

*Workarounds:
Some users mentioned this article was helpful* *https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016336611-Revert-Back-to-Earlier-Version-or-Add-Custom-Build-to-Chrome*